# Python module to remove bad or curse words from the line and block

Tags: python, methods

I am working one Python module which should take a line of text and remove if there are any bad words or curse word.
it should block the bad word too.
Can anyone help me to fix?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way and simple way to deal with this is:

Just initialize a set with few bad words and curse words
For eg: `s={"badass", "asshole"}`

Now when you are taking a string just divide the string into list of words by using 
nltk word_tokenize module and then take the intersection words between both sets

So you will be ending with bad words used in a string then just remove them and again make a string

If you can do it by code then no problem
else comment

Answer (score 0):

Just make a list with badword like this `badwords = ["asshole","idiot"]`

Now replace it

```
badwords = ["asshole","idiot"]
text = "Its a idiot."
for badword in badwords:
        text = text.replace(badword,"*"*len(badword))
```